# Unable to resolve dependencies of spring boot in intellij idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am new to spring boot. I have tried several solutions but none of them worked.

- added certificate of maven to jdk
- tried deleting .m2 folder and .idea folder
- tried invalidating cache and restarting ide
- tried toggling , adding and removing maven project
- tried updating repositories also
- tried adding VM options for importing  ""-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true

Nothing worked.
This is a screenshot of the errors I am getting.
[image]

Using jdk version - 18.0.1.1
maven version - 3.8.5
spring boot version - 2.7.1

Please help what am I missing or which other tools I should use to create a web project using spring boot and java

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem or not, but I frequently have to point intellij at a specific maven install, rather the using the bundled version.

Comment: In past it helped mostly at me: Go to your local maven repository, remove the repository.xml and the folder of your missing dependencies. After that open a console or command window and do  a build with mvn install

Comment: Have you tried removing .mvn folder in your user's directory?

Comment: tried that didn't work. I settled using eclipse with sts studio